# Functions for pruning a NetworkX graph?

Tags: networkx

I am using NetworkX to generate graphs of some noisy data. I'd like to "clean up" the graph by removing branches that are spurious, and hope to avoid re-inventing the wheel.

For example, the linked picture shows a sample set of graphs, as colored nodes connected by gray lines. I'd like to prune the nodes/edges indicated by the white boxes: http://www.broadinstitute.org/~mbray/example_tree.png

Essentially, the nodes/edges to be removed are branches typically only a few nodes (< 3) in length. By removing them, I hope to have a tree with a minimum of branching but the branches that do remain are "suitably" long.

Before I start crafting code to examine subtrees for removal, are there NetworkX functions that can be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the betweenness_centrality score of the nodes.  If the node with a low centrality score is connected to a node of remarkably higher centrality score, and has 3 edges, then you can remove the low centrality node.  (the rest of the <3 connected nodes aren't connected to the main graph anymore.).

You'll need to experiment with the phrase "remarkably higher".

Comment: I like this, at least as a start. The branches are usually quite asymmetric, so finding a pruning threshold shouldn't be too hard. Thanks!